# What is GIT (program that Linus created)

Tags: kernel, git

This question might not be appropriate for this exact forum however I am sure that everyone here knows. I looked at multiple definitions and can't figure out exactly what it is. If anyone could explain what it is and where it's used in simple terms that would be great, Thanks in advance and sorry for posting in the wrong forum.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control before this gets taken down

Comment: ok so its for managing opensource software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try with simple terms:

Git is a program where you can save your files in a repository and make versions of these files. This means you can share a document with another person and both of you can modify these documents and know exactly who wrote each line!

Besides that, if you accidently removed a line or the entire document you can restore it to a previous version!

I hope my explanation helped you.

Comment: best explanation!